# Google reCaptcha on more domains

Tags: recaptcha

How to use Google reCaptcha on more domains? I have tried with security token (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token) in **PHP** and not work.

Answer (score 1):

I know, it's an old questions. Just wanted to update the link.

A recaptcha key is normally tied to a set of individual domains. However, if your list of valid domains is extremely long, fluid, or unknown, we give you the option to turn off the domain name checking on recaptcha's end, and instead check on your server.

https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation